# Overriding hashcode and equals in java

Tags: java

I am unclear about use of hashcode and equals method in java.I have following query

**First**

If I Override only equals method all objects of value Fred are added though HashSet implements set interface,which cant take repeated values.

**Second**
If i override both equals and hashcode only one object is added to HashSet.Why?

**Third**
If I implement only equals in this case will removing  one Fred object will remove all?

```
class Person
{
    String name;
    Person(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(!(obj instanceof Person))
        {
       return false;
         }
    Person p = (Person)obj;
    return p.name.equals(this.name);
       }


    /*@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }*/
}

public class HashSetDemo {

    /*
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HashSet<Person> s= new HashSet<Person>();
        s.add(new Person("Fred"));
        s.add(new Person("Fred"));
        s.add(new Person("Fred"));
        s.add(new Person("Fred1"));
        for(Person a:s) {
            System.out.println(a.name);
        }

        s.remove(new Person("Fred"));
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks suspiciously like homework. If it is, tag it as such.

Comment: @prerna for extensive explanation check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From "Effective Java" by Joshua Bloch, Item 9:

> **You must override `hashCode` in every class that overrides `equals`.**  Failure to do so will result in a violation of the general contract for `Object.hashCode`, which will prevent your class from functioning properly in conjunction with all hash-based collections, including `HashMap`, `HashSet`, and `Hashtable`.

The Eclipse IDE will generate a `hashCode` and `equals` method for you.

Most `hashCode` methods look something like this:

```
public int hashCode() {
    int result = 17;
    result = 31 * result + field1;   (int)
    result = 31 * result + field2.hashCode();   (Object)
    ... for the rest of the fields.
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your equals method is `this.name == emp.name` this checks if the two strings point to the same memory you should be using `equals` instead `this.name.equals(emp.name)`.  That will solve your first issue.

The `hashCode` method tells you how to convert to `hashCode`. Since you made the `hashCode` equal to the name's `hashCode` all the `Freds` have the same `hashCode` So they all overwrite each other in the `HashSet`. This answers your second question.

I don't know `HashSet's` exact implementation but with the First issue solved this won't be a problem.

Comment: I have changed the code by using equals it still prints Fred three times

Comment: You didn't uncomment `HashCode`. The `HashCode` method determines whether the `HashSet` will work properly. Look at Gilbert Le Blanc's answer. Also if you do `Person p = new Person("Fred"); Person p1 = new Person("Fred"); System.out.println(p.equals(p1));` you'll get `true` printed.